# Stuck with type conversion of lat and long in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to print the lat and long of a particular place as it is into a string but whenever I try doing it the output, however, is not as expected, for e.g

```
long = -66.75218
```

when I do print(long) the output is

```
-66.75218000000001
```

I want the output to be the same as the input,

maybe the question is trivial but I am stuck with it.

Answer (score 0):

simply use round function

round(3.1415, 2)
= 3.14

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, use `round()` or format a string.

```
val = -66.75218000000001

print(round(val, 5))  -> -66.75218
```

Or an f-string:

```
 print(f"{val:.5f}")
```

Or `format()`:

```
print("{:.5f}".format(val))
```